# Paypal IPN with Zencart

Tags: paypal

I'm settion up zencart for selling goods.
On the Admin section, it needed to be install IPN(Instant Payment Notification).
But i can't find IPN preference on my paypal account > Profile.

My Account > Profile > My selling tools

There are only 3 menus.

eBay ID
PayPal buttons
Invoice templates

Should i needed upgrade my account type to business? (Curently my account is personnel)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked my account and I can find the settings in:

> Profile > My Selling Preferences > Instant payment notifications

Comment: Weird.. I'm still can't find that menu. Are you "Personnel" Account?

Comment: I've just checked and its "Premier"

Comment: It's because of account type. I switched to premier and i can see that menu. Thanks.